# How to create a wall using SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, line, swift2, nodes

How do you create a wall that follows your touch?

I currently create multiple nodes that are all small circles "brick.png", but I would prefer it to be continuous and only one node to save memory.

Currently creates:

[image: Small Nodes]

I want the circles near the goal to be a continuous line requiring one node.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpriteKit has SKShapeNode. You can use it to draw a CGPath on the screen. In thochesMoved you recalculate the path and set to the path property.